# Jekyll Download files from _data folder

Tags: markdown, jekyll

here is my _data folder

```
_data:
    abc.csv
```

and in md file, I wanted to download that CSV file using a button for example
`<a href="Link to _data folder" download="">download Raw CSV</a>`
how can I achieve this?

I have tried
`<a href="<path to _data folder and filename>" download="">download Raw CSV</a>`
it is returning me 404 not found error when I click download.

Answer (score 1):

Data Files are not handled in the same fashion as your posts, documents and pages. Instead, data files are *just parsed* into Ruby objects for use while rendering of your posts, documents and pages.

To get Jekyll to create physical files from data files, you'll need a Ruby plugin. You can either write the plugin yourselves or get someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have the ability to download the file, put a copy in a `assets` folder. You will be able to link to the file directly from this path.